# Joining tables in activerecord based on a column of the first table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

I want to accomplish a join like this:

```
MyModel.joins(:other_model).
where(column: 123, other_model { other_column: column_in_my_model })
```

In practice, this would be something like

```
SELECT * FROM my_model m
INNER JOIN other_model o on m.column = o.foreign_key
WHERE m.column = 123 AND o.other_column = m.column_in_my_model
```

In the activerecord version, there's no way to refer to `column_in_my_model` that I know of without passing an SQL string. Is it possible to do this with activerecord syntax without passing a raw SQL string? Arel is OK too.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this

```
MyModel.joins(:other_model)
       .where(my_model_column: 123)
       .where('column_in_my_model = other_model_column')
```

Comment: Thank you. I'm aware that this sort of thing works, but it passes SQL as a string. I'm asking if it's possible to do this without that.

Comment: that's the best you can do with `activerecord` AFAIK

Answer (score 0):

```
MyModel.find(:all,
  :joins=>" JOIN other_model_table_name ON other_model_table_name.column = my_models.column",
  :conditions=>"my_models.column = '123' AND other_model_table_name.column = my_models.column"
)
```